# loops seems to be skipping urls

Tags: python, riot-games-api

I have a list full of urls for RIOT API's. For some odd reason, it seems to be skipping many of the urls(20 in them) and only printing 3 different urls. I've did print(url) and it shows all of the urls.
What suppose to happen is it goes through each game url in the riot API and print the deaths in each game(20 in total). Instead it posted 3 game deaths

```
 for urls in game_list:

            response=requests.get(urls)
            Loop=0
            
            while Loop<=10:
                index=0
                if response.json()['participantIdentities'][index]['player']['summonerName']!=sumName:
                    Loop= Loop+1
                    index=index+1
                elif response.json()['participantIdentities'][index]['player']['summonerName']==sumName:

                    deaths.append(response.json()['participants'][index]['stats']['deaths'])
                    kills.append(response.json()['participants'][index]['stats']['kills'])
                    assists.append(response.json()['participants'][index]['stats']['assists'])
                    visions.append(response.json()['participants'][index]['stats']['visionScore'])
                    csTotal.append(response.json()['participants'][index]['stats']['totalMinionsKilled'])
                    print(deaths)
                    break
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Your posted code fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should put everything in the while loop inside of a Try/Except, and under "Except" put Break. It's because there is nothing more to loop for.
Another way would just do a for loop and loop through everything in participantIdentities.